# Create html anchor in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a link to a specific page section id.

It's something like the bellow html, but I want to use rails instead...

```
<a id="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>

<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

How can I specify the "#tips" in the link_to function? Or should I create a specific route? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

`<%= link_to "Visit the Useful Tips Section", action_path(anchor: tips) %>`

In routes you can specify the `action_path`.

As per Rails API docs you should do the above way, please refer [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), and find below example :

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using link_to

```
<%= link_to "Visit the Useful Tips Section","/#tips" %>
```

assuming you are linking to an id on the same page

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= link_to('new button', action: 'login' , class: "text-center") %>
```

created an anchor tag for login.html i.g

```
<a href="login.html" class = "text-center"> new button </a>
```

and for

```
<a href="admin/login.html" class = "text-center"> new button </a>
```

use

```
<%= link_to('new button', controller: 'admin',
action: 'login' , class: "text-center") %>
```